# Win32 console write (C/C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to write to the console in a C++ program without using the 'std' libraries, that is, just using the functions in "Windows.h".  The reason is I want to dig into the portable executable and see this one function being called, not a bunch of function layers.  Anyone know how to do this and/or where I can find a guide to the "Windows.h" functions?

Comment: FWIW, for writing to the console, there's a function literally called `WriteConsole`. It has variants, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using pure Win APIs:

```
HANDLE stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if (stdOut != NULL && stdOut != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD written = 0;
    const char *message = "hello world";
    WriteConsoleA(stdOut, message, strlen(message), &written, NULL);
}
```

MSDN is one of your best sources for documentation:

- [GetStdHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231.aspx)
- [WriteConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401.aspx)

Comment: If `GetStdHandle` or `WriteConsole` return false, then you may need to use `AllocConsole`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative Win32 API:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << TEXT("Hello world!") << std::endl;

    OutputDebugString(ss.str().c_str());

    OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
#endif

#ifdef UNICODE
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << TEXT("Hello world!") << std::endl;

    OutputDebugString(ss.str().c_str());

    OutputDebugStringW(wss.str().c_str());
#endif
```

<sub>* *OutputDebugString is a macro.*</sub>

**Reference:**

- [Use `OutputDebugString` when debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/debug)
- [OutputDebugStringA function (debugapi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa)
- [OutputDebugStringW function (debugapi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw)